# 2x2 Matrix (M), where a and b commute so detM = I detM

Tags: matrices

2x2 Matrix M [a b]
__________[c d]

M^-1 = 1/(ad-bc) [d -b]
____________[-c a]

If a and b commute, M^-1 = I(ad-bc)^-1 [d -b]
____________________________[-c a]

I is the 2x2 identity matrix

Could you please explain how that works?

edit:
Where a, b, c and d are 2x2 matrices

Comment: What do you mean by "a and b commute"? Are a and b numbers or matrices?

Comment: they are matrices

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are matrices, then how are we supposed to interpret
$$
(ad - bc)^{-1} \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}
$$
the matrices being multiplied here are nonconformable

Comment: Also, please see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) on how to format math on this site.

Comment: In any case, the formula for the inverse of a $2\times 2$ block matrix can be derived using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)

Comment: what are u talking about? all matrices are 2x2. I still don't understand what  do you want to do. $M^{-1}=(AD-BC)^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} D & -B \\ -C & A \\ \end{pmatrix}$ works as far as $AD-BC$ can even be inverted (so $det(AD-BC) \neq 0$)

Comment: and what's with that commutation? so A and B commute, what about C and D ?

Comment: oh i know what don't see! if $A,B,C$ are $n x n$ matrices then for example $A\begin{pmatrix} B & 1 \\ 0 & C \\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} AB & A \\ 0 & AC \\ \end{pmatrix}$. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \end{pmatrix}$is not the same as$\begin{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \\ \end{pmatrix} \\ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \\ \end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 6 & 7 \\ \end{pmatrix} \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This in general does not work. Your $M^{-1}$ is neither a left inverse nor a right inverse of $M$. The problem is that multiplication of "scalars" in your case is not commutative. However, if all the "scalars" $a,b,c,d$ here are by themselves matrices over a field, **and** they all commute with each other (not just among $a$ and $b$) **and** $ad-bc$ is invertible , then $a,b,c,d$ will also commute with the "scalar" $(ad-bc)^{-1}$ and your $M^{-1}$ is indeed a (left and right) inverse of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $a,b,c,d\in \mathcal M_2(F)$ for some field $F$ and $M\in \mathcal M_2(\mathcal M_2(F))$.

What you've described does not work. Your $M^{-1}$ is neither a left inverse nor a right inverse of $M$. The problem is that multiplication of "scalars" in your case is not commutative. In particular, $(ad-bc)^{-1}$ does not necessarily commute with $a,b,c$ or $d$.

However, if all the "scalars" $a,b,c,d$ here are by themselves matrices over a field, **and** they all commute with each other (not just among $a$ and $b$) **and** $ad-bc$ is invertible , then $a,b,c,d$ will automatically commute with the "scalar" $(ad-bc)^{-1}$ and your $M^{-1}$ is indeed a (left and right) inverse of $M$.

That said, concerning determinants, we do have the following result. Let
$$M'=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}a&b\\ \hline c&d\end{array}\right]\in \mathcal M_4(F)$$
(which is a $4\times4$ matrix over the field $F$) be the block matrix whose four sub-blocks are $a,b,c,d\in \mathcal M_2(F)$. The difference between $M$ and $M'$ is that $M$ is a $2\times2$ matrix whose entries are taken from $\mathcal M_2(F)$, while $M'$ is a $4\times4$ matrix whose entries are taken directly from $F$. Provided that $ab=ba$, we have
$$
\det M'=\det(da-cb)
$$
(where the left hand side is the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix over $F$ and the right hand side is the determinant of a $2\times2$ matrix over $F$).

Note that in the above, we only need $ab=ba$; we don't need all four matrices $a,b,c,d$ to commute. In general, however, if $M'$ is a block matrix of larger size (say, it has 3 blocks by 3 blocks), then to guarantee that we can do something similar, we do need all sub-blocks to commute with each other. This is a result by John Silvester and this has been discussed a couple of times on this site. See my [answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801957), for instance.

Comment: > However, if all the "scalars" a,b,c,da,b,c,d here are by themselves matrices over a field, and they all commute with each other (not just among aa and bb) and ad−bcad−bc is invertible , then a,b,c,da,b,c,d will automatically commute with the "scalar" (ad−bc)−1(ad−bc)−1 and your M−1M−1 is indeed a (left and right) inverse of MM.  
Why?

Comment: @FrancisTP If $a,b,c,d$ commute, they commute with $ad-bc$ too. Yet $(ad-bc)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $ad-bc$ (Cayley-Hamilton theorem). Hence $a,b,c,d$ commute with $(ad-bc)^{-1}$.